# Subdividing a Mask

Tags: masking

Is there any way to subdivide an already created mask.  I'm working on a project where I have already manually masked about 50 frames (about 2 hours' worth of work), when i realized that there aren't enough vertices (is that the word?) in the mask.  Is there any way to fix this without just making a separate mask?

Comment: What would the drawback be of creating an additional mask? When rotoscoping complex shapes, having multiple masks for various parts is quite usual.

Comment: For this particular structure I'm rotoscoping a person, and don't have enough verticies for the legs, so I don't really know how to make it not look super awkward to have two separate masks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not be afraid of making more than one mask. It is a lot easier to rotoscope using multiple masks for different sections. Work with simpler shapes, they are a lot easier to manage than a single, larger, more complex one with lots of vertices (or control points).

Having multiple masks will allow you much finer control: you can turn some  on or off, vary the feathering and have detail only where you really need it.

See how many masks are used in the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NR9w2TRWRlI

[image]

or:

[image]

You can combine different masks directly as layers

as done in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=482&v=5ZnJLLB1P4M

Or you can combine them in the compositor.

Use a color mix node to subtract, multiply or combine different masks in different ways.

Related: [Separate Masks in Node Editor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73302/separate-masks-in-node-editor)

Another tip is to use the tracking tools in blender and associate the trackers with point of the mask to automate the process.

See:

[Is it possible to take a mask clip and 'connect' it to a specific point on a moving object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23865/is-it-possible-to-take-a-mask-clip-and-connect-it-to-a-specific-point-on-a-mov/23902#23902)