# Track Matte Key Effect for VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Is there TRACK MATTE KEY effect for Blender Video Sequence Editor? I use this effect for Videos in Adobe Premiere Pro for Overlay Transitions of .MOV files. Not knowing how to do in Blender, I used Blend modes for these effects, but they don't work exactly as desired like with Track Matte Key effect.

Thank you,
Bhat

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23865/is-it-possible-to-take-a-mask-clip-and-connect-it-to-a-specific-point-on-a-mov

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24408/can-a-mask-stick-to-a-shape-in-the-motion-tracker?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135558/subdividing-a-mask?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174215/how-do-i-animate-an-image-in-the-video-sequence-editor-to-match-the-underlying-v?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

You need to work "effects" in the compositor.
It seems you need to track and key at the same time.
If this is the case, you will first need to address the track (movie clip editor), once you generate your 8 obligatory tracking points, you can attach whatever you need, then use the 3D space to "stick" your motion graphics plane (or .mov), and finally go to the compositor window and now work the part of the keying.
[image]
Ian Hubert shows different techniques that might be helpful to your workflow here:
https://youtu.be/RxD6H3ri8RI

If you need further assistance with your question, please let us know. Thanks!

Comment: No, there is no need for an obligatory number of tracking points. Unless you are doing 3D reconstruction, you don't have to solve the scene, so there is no need for a specific number of trackers. To automate mask creation you can use motion tracking and use the tracking information in 2D either by using in the compostitor or controlling vertices in the 3D environment. Trackers can be associated with control points of mask to facilitate rotoscoping or "Tracked Matte keying".

Comment: I will post a example with a video of Overlay transitions for Premiere Pro. It is a less than 3 min. video first with examples and then how Track Matte Key is used for Overlay transitions. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfXfEi_VsGc

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the Matte type "track matte" between tracks in After effects"? I believe that is where you define a track's clip to be the mAsk shape or alpha channel for a key effect. This can be achieved in THE VSE by adding  background clip then a mask shape image or movie or actual Blender masks a strip. Then above this you place a foreground or fill clip/strip. then in this Strip's Property panel you apply an effect MASK modifier. Then in the strip filed select the mask strip name. If the mask strip appears in the key effect, then go to the Mask strip and set its opacity property to 0%